How to manage test properties between two modules in a multi-module Maven project?
I have a multi-module Maven project with two modules: network and devenv. The project structure looks like this:
service
├── network
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   ├── test
│   │   │   └── resources
│   │   │       └── application-bridge-to-bridge-test.properties
│   └── resources
├── devenv
│   └── resources
│       └── application.properties (contains all properties needed for production)
└── pom.xml


The network module's tests need to initialize properties from application.properties and then override certain values using application-bridge-to-bridge-test.properties (which are specific to the network tests).

Locally, I managed this by adding the following to my network test class:


@TestPropertySource(locations = {
        "file:../devenv/src/main/resources/application.properties.properties",
        "classpath:application-bridge-to-bridge-test.properties"
})

This works fine locally, but when the pipeline triggers the tests on CI/CD, I get the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add PropertySource to Environment...

Additional constraint:
We cannot import the devenv module into network because network is a dependency of devenv. This circular dependency would break the build.
My question is:

Is there a way to resolve this issue so that the tests work in the CI/CD pipeline?
What is the best practice for managing shared properties between modules to avoid duplication? The network and devenv properties files are mostly identical, and it’s easy for developers to forget to update both files when changes are made.

Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

You might consider extracting all public configuration from the application.properties file in devenv into a new application-common.properties file. This new file should be located in a module that both devenv and network have introduced.
At this point you can introduce it like this
@TestPropertySource({“classpath: application-common.properties”})
Maybe
@TestPropertySource({“classpath*:application-common.properties”})
I'm sorry I haven't used it this way. If you consider a configuration center (e.g. nacos), it might be easier.
